# Cloning Hash & update a value in a single line

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been looking for an elegant way to update a nested cloned Hash

So far I got this nested Hash

```
h1 = {
  show: true,
  format: {
      args: []
  }
}
```

I need to use to diuplicate h1's hash and append a key/value pair without modifying the original hash.

For exemple I can simply do this :

```
h2 = h1.clone
```

then

```
h2[:format][:new_key] = true
```

Which will provide us this results

```
> h2
{:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>[], :new_key=>true}}
```

How can I perform this operation in a single line? And can I avoid having `h1` affected ?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview2/Object.html#method-i-tap)

```
h2 = h1.deep_dup.tap { |h| h[:format][:new_key] = true }
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I avoid `h1` being affected ?

Comment: I moved to a `deep_dup`, you can find some different options here on SO if you look for this subject.

Comment: The `deep_dup` method you posted is not called at all. Although that is inconsequential since rails already implements [`Hash#deep_dup`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Hash/deep_dup) facilitated by [`Object#deep_dup`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Object/deep_dup) among others.

Comment: yeah, you're right, sorry. now should use the one from rails

Answer (score 2):

Seems the right solution would be

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1)).tap {|h|
  h[:format][:new_key] = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h2 = h1.merge(:format=>{ args: h1[:format][:args].dup, newley: true })
  #=> {:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>[], :newley=>true}}
```

If we modify `h2`:

```
h2[:format][:args] << 9
  #=> [9] 
h2 #=> {:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>[9], :newley=>true}}
```

`h1` remains unchanged:

```
h1 #=> {:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>[]}}
```

---

Suppose the array `h1[:format][:args]` is not empty:

```
h1 = { show: true, format: { args: ['cat'] } }
```

Then

```
h2 = h1.merge(:format=>{ args: h1[:format][:args].dup, newley: true })
  #=> {:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>["cat"], :newley=>true}}
```

If we modify `h2`:

```
h2[:format][:args] << 9
  #=> ["cat", 9] 
h2 #=> {:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>["cat", 9], :newley=>true}}
```

`h1` remains unchanged:

```
h1 #=> {:show=>true, :format=>{:args=>["cat"]}}
```

Comment: What if `h1[:format][:args]` is not empty?